# Recommend a Terminal app for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, terminal, software-recommendation

Can anyone recommend a terminal emulator for iOS 13.3.1?

I’m kinda green to the whole thing to be completely honest! So any extra advice would be wonderful!

Comment: it might help if you said what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would support reopening this if someone took a stab at what requirements are for this software? Is it copper serial port terminal? Telnet? Ssh? Mosh? Is it to run a shell locally and not even require the terminal go anywhere off the device? https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation

Answer (score 4):

I use Prompt 2 by Panic. It's an excellent terminal app / SSH client, and works on the iPad too (in fact, it's even better on the iPad).

However, it's not free.

Comment: $14.99 USD on the App Store for iPhone and iPad. Also "This app may use your location even when it isn't open, which can decrease battery life."

Comment: Location is to get around the 30 second timeout. You don’t need to enable it unless you want that feature. The story behind this is quite fascinating https://library.panic.com/general/ios-background/ thanks for mentioning it @user3439894

Comment: @user3439894 see my edited comment. Serious thanks for raising it, I’m sure others will see the same review as you and have questions.

Comment: Does Prompt 2 provide a basic “local” filesystem/environment? It would be nice to have something for offline git repos.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer apps that are cross platform so that I don't have to "learn" different apps on different devices.

Once such App is [Termius](https://www.termius.com/pricing).  There's a free tier, as well as a "pro" tier that allows you to sync across devices regardless of OS.  It supports iOS, macOS, Windows, Android and Linux.

Disclaimer:  I don't use it on macOS because I prefer iTerm2 there, but I do use it on my iOS and Windows devices and (reluctantly when I have to) on Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

I use openTerm myself. I use this to bring up the command line on my iPad. OpenTerm is $3.99 on the App Store. A free app is LibTerm also available on the App Store. These allow you to access the file system on the iPad among other things. You can also send commands to your iPad. I would suggest using LibTerm to see if it does what you want. It's hard to give more advice without knowing more about what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: [OpenTerm App Store Preview](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/openterm/id1481149807) and [LibTerm App Store Preview](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/libterm/id1380911705)

Comment: OpenTerm is no longer available in many countries’ App Store.  I do use it and love that it’s open sourced. Great option if you can buy it or had already bought it as it’s still available for download to previous purchasers.

Answer (score 2):

Get your own local terminal with [LibTerm](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/libterm/id1380911705)

For network ssh use [Prompt](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/prompt-2/id917437289)

I would expect some very specific requirements if another than these apps would be the best recommended apps in 2020.