# App that displays real or fake busy data-visualization?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm working on an indie film that needs the cliché l33t hAxX0r **"really busy screen (with cascading Matrix-y code and scanning and maps and other cryptic junk) that looks sophisticated, but make real geeks scoff with ridicule"**, as used in every cybercrime analysis or hacker scene in the history of cinema (except for Mr. Robot, who actually got it right).

Are there any apps that do this purely aesthetic cyber readout data-visualization overkill?

Or any ready-to-go presets for apps that might look similar, like iTerm?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383910/recommend-a-terminal-app-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the many Matrix-y screensavers around:

https://miteshshah.github.io/mac/redpill-matrix-screen-saver-for-mac-os/

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/matrixgl.html

https://github.com/winterbe/github-matrix-screensaver

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a screensaver could help - I got this collection from JWZ - [XScreenSaver](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/download.html) which consists of 200+ retro 'computery things'.
TBH, I've never been through the whole lot, so idk really what's there. I use a large array of 'crash screen/system errors' which freaks people out ;-)

Comment: Some interesting stuff in there!

Answer (score 0):

[htop](https://htop.dev/sightings.html) is an app that has actually been found in several movies including Mr. Robot.

To get `htop` to show some activity, have it convert some audio or video files with `ffmpeg` or execute `yes` a few times and push it to the background with the command `yes > /dev/null &`